# \newpage command not starting a new page in mcexam

Tags: mcexam

The command `\newpage` does not begin a new page in `mcexam`.  I need the `\begin{mcquestioninstruction}` to begin on the next page because it is orphaned from the questions that follow.

*Update:* `\newpage` *is now inserted **after** the `\begin{mcquestioninstruction}` line.  This does put the instruction on the next page as desired.*

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam
           ,numberofversions=2
           ,version=1
           ,seed=1
           ,randomizequestions=false
           ,randomizeanswers=true
           ,writeRfile=true
           ]{mcexam}
\usepackage{tikz,framed} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\hyphenpenalty=2000
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\lfoot{\mctheversion}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\labelwidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}  
 
\begin{document}
\mcifoutput{concept,exam}

\section*{}
\begin{mcquestions}
    \question Question 1
        \begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
        \answer [correct] answer 1
        \answer answer 2
        \answer answer 3
        \answer answer 4
        \end{mcanswerslist}
    \begin{mcquestioninstruction}
    \newpage
    My instructions that must be at the top of the next page:
    \end{mcquestioninstruction}
    \question Question 2
        \begin{mcanswerslist}%[fixlast]
        \answer answer 1
        \answer answer 2
        \answer answer 3
        \answer answer 4
        \end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want Question 2 to be on the same page as Question 1? Or everything after `\newpage` is on a new page, hard to understand as you describe it as `orphaned` from the questions that follow. Moving `\newpage` within `\begin{mcquestioninstruction}` creates a new page but Question 2 is on it too, could you clarify please

Comment: I am wanting Question 2 on the 2nd page after the ```\begin{mcquestioninstruction}```.  Your solution achieved what I needed.

Comment: If you want to allow pagebreaks in some locations (between) but not others (inside), use more than one minipage.

Answer (score 2):

you are inserting a `minipage` the only function of which is to prevent page breaking.

Comment out this line

```
%\renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\labelwidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}
```

[image]

Comment: Commenting out that line would work great except then the multiple choice responses can get split over a page break.

Comment: @larryjby yes sure but you phased the question as `\newpage` not working in mcexam, but the package is not relevant here. it is  "`\newpage` not working in `minipage` inserted by the document author"   and since the only function of minipage here is to prevent page breaking, "don't use `minipage` " seems the natural answer.

Comment: The use of ```minipage``` is from the original author of mcexam.  (I removed the comments acknowledging the author ```Copyright (c) 2017 Jorre Vannieuwenhuyze``` to reduce the lines of code in my example.)  I will need a way to keep questions/multiple responses together, yet allow page breaks within the lists of questions.

Comment: your first line "The command \newpage does not begin a new page in mcexam. " is simply false. `\newpage` works in mcexam as I show here. It does not work (by design) in the `minipage` you do not mention but leave people to find in your code @larryjb

Comment: try `\renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\samepage}{}` @larryjb

Comment: To clarify, this is not my code, I was not intending to "leave people to find" it.  I now understand that the minipage environment is responsible for some of the effects I have been observing.  I just need to find a way to work around it.  I have left an e-mail with the original author to see if he knows a work-around.